# Can not upload Unity WebGL in ASP.Net with an error of "The error was: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-game-engine

I built some sample game in Unity in WebGL and it worked well locally. However, when I tried to put it on my ASP.net MVC, it did not work.

I simply created my ASP.NET MVC project and copied my Unity WebGl Build into the project.

[My ASP.NET MVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3jtp.png)

But when I ran the web project and opened my Unity WebGL Build, I got an error of "An error occurred running the Unity content on this page. See your browser JavaScript console for more info. The error was: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<"

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVFgs.png)

If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please kindly help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ....and did you follow the advice of that dialog? You know the "See your browser JavaScript console for more info." When error messages give you hints, it's generally best to follow them and not to just ignore them and post on [SO]. Show us the console message and maybe we can help.

Comment: In other words,
1) Post your code in the question as preformatted text, not as a screenshot.
2) When it says to go to the JavaScript console for more info, _[go to the JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) for more info_. If you still don't get it, at least post it with the question.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to create Web.config file and place it in the root category of your project.

The content of the file would be:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
　　　　　　<staticContent>
　　　　　　<mimeMap fileExtension=".mem" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
　　　　　　<mimeMap fileExtension=".unityweb" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
　　　　　　<mimeMap fileExtension=".data" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
　　　　　　<mimeMap fileExtension=".memgz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
　　　　　　<mimeMap fileExtension=".datagz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
　　　　　　<mimeMap fileExtension=".unity3dgz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
　　　　　　<mimeMap fileExtension=".jsgz" mimeType="application/x-javascript;charset=UTF-8" />
　　　　</staticContent>
　　</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I fixed my issue with this web.config file

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my unclear question.

First, I did not write any code. The code in the first picture is from the html file built by Unity

I navigated further into JavaScript console. I got the following error:

[Error for Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Lqp.jpg)

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

TypeError:UnityLoader[r] is not a function in UnityLoader.js

Note: It works properly locally.

Thank you.